# Python Kivy rotating an image using an integer

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm using the Kivy library to make a gauge display for a data logger system that i've coded through Arduino and Raspberry Pi using Python on the Pi end

I am trying to rotate an image (gauge needle) in relation to an integer variable (oil temp)

The python code stores the integer fine but i'm struggling to set the rotation of an image based on an integer in Kivy

Am I better to do this in Kivy or to use something easier like PyGame?

This is my Python/Kivy code currently which displays the gauge image and the needle on top of each other but the area I am stuck with is in the second image

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

float = OilTemp = 180

class CustomRow(FloatLayout):
    pass


class CustomGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass


kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Widget:    
        
    RelativeLayout:  
        Image:
            source: 'OilTempV3.png'
            size_hint: (1, 0.5)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0} 
        Image:
            source: 'NeedleV1.png'
            size_hint: (1, 0.48)
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: OilTemp
                    origin: self.center
'''


class RotationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


RotationApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set an attribute in `kv` to a plain variable, that attribute gets set to the value of that variable at the time that the `kv` is loaded. Changing the variable after that will have no effect on the attribute in the `kv`. If you want the attribute to track the changes, you should use a `Property`. You can create a `NumericProperty`, but any `Property` must be created in an `EventDispatcher`, like a `Widget` or an `App`:

```
class RotationApp(App):
    OilTemp = NumericProperty(180)
```

Then, in the `kv`, you can use this `Property` as `app.OilTemp`:

```
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: app.OilTemp
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
```

You should normally include a `PopMatrix` afterwards to limit the effect of the `Rotate`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That seems to make more sense but it doesn't seem to like the NumericPropety. Is there another line that I need to define it?

Comment: The line `OilTemp = NumericProperty(180)` defines the `NumericProperty`. Note that it should appear as I have shown, inside the `RotationApp` class, but not in any method.

Comment: I was putting it in the wrong place, rookie mistake. Thanks for all the help